# Count rows that do not contain a string

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
 #df
 Factors    Transactions
  a,c             1
  b               0
  c               0
 d,a              0
  a               1
  a               0 
  b               1
```

I'd like to know how many times we did **not** have a factor and we had a transaction. So, my desirable output is as follows:

```
 #desired output
 Factors     count
  a            1
  b            2
  c            2
  d            3
```

For instance, only one time we didn't have `a` and we had a transaction (i.e. only in the last row).

There are many ways to know how many times we had each factor and we had transactions. For instance I tried this one:

```
 library(data.table)

 setDT(df)[, .(Factors = unlist(strsplit(as.character(Factors), ","))), 
  by = Transactions][,.(Transactions = sum(Transactions > 0)), by = Factors]
```

But I wish to count how many times we **didn't** have a factor and we had transaction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the opposite, i.e, how many times the factor has a transaction and then the difference between the total transactions and transactions for each individual factor would be what you are looking for:

```
library(data.table)
total <- sum(df$Transactions > 0)

(setDT(df)[, .(Factors = unlist(strsplit(as.character(Factors), ","))), Transactions]
          [, total - sum(Transactions > 0), Factors])

#   Factors V1
#1:       a  1
#2:       c  2
#3:       b  2
#4:       d  3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "Factors", ',', 'long')[, sum(df$Transactions) - sum(Transactions>0), Factors]
#   Factors V1
#1:       a  1
#2:       c  2
#3:       b  2
#4:       d  3
```

---

Or with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, Factors) %>% 
          group_by(Factors) %>%
          summarise(count = sum(df$Transactions) - sum(Transactions>0))
```